# Feature suggestion for android app - deleting answers

Tags: feature-request, android-app

I'm beta testing the new android app. I was hoping that it would be possible to delete my own answers on it but that doesn't seem to be the case. Often when I am on the site I am at work where forums are blocked, so I have to use my phone (I do get my work done, I promise). Sometimes I post answers too soon, and in order to delete them I need to go to the full site in chrome. It's not the end of the world, but it would be nice to have the feature readily accessible on the app. Is it too late in the game to put it into this version? Or does anyone disagree that it should be put in?

I'm also at work on my phone at this very moment, and I'm using chrome because while I see the general stack exchange meta on the app, I haven't see the math meta.

Comment: I think this should be on [Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/) rather than our meta.

Comment: @MikeMiller yeah you're probably right. Is it possible to migrate it myself it do we need votes?

Comment: I've flagged a moderator to migrate it.

Comment: @MikeMiller thanks.

Comment: [Help us test the Stack Exchange Android tablet app](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245731/help-us-test-the-stack-exchange-android-tablet-app)

Comment: @MikeMiller No need to migrate since it'd be closed as a duplicate there. [Allow us to vote to delete from the Android app](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216962/). Also, the SE Mobile Team monitors (android-app) tag network wide, so as long as it's on the question, it's visible. I added the tag.

Comment: @AsafKaragila It renders with an extra tap. There is a good technical reason why it cannot render in place. (MathJax runs in a browser, and an app is not a browser).